# iOS 6 - When to instantiate (create an object of the class) and when not to?

Tags: ios, object, initialization, instantiation

I am trying to understand the instantiation process better.  I understand that some classes need to be allocated and initialized (I have to create an object of the class) before I can use them, such as NSMutableArray.  However, I am running into classes that I do not need to instantiate before I use them, such as NSDate and UIImage.

For example, I have always been instantiating NSMutableArray like this before I can use it:

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

With UIImage I can just skip instantiation and just do this:

```
UIImage *i = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
```

Are there any rules or tell-a-signs for when I can just use a class without instantiating and when I have to instantiate?  I'm trying to see if there is a quick way of knowing this.

Thanks!

Comment: The object is still being instantiated internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are always instantiating an object in either case. It is just that the `UIImage` class provides some static convenience methods that hide the rather ugly alloc/init process. Even `NSMutableArray` has `[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numItems]` which still does 'alloc', 'init' inside of it but also sets up an initial capacity (for performance reasons). The best way is to peruse the docs, looking for static class methods, or seeing if autocomplete has any methods that begin with the thing you are making, e.g. `[UIImage image...]` and `[NSDate date...]`

Answer (score 1):

In general, my own rule of thumb is if the object is only going live within that method and not be used outside the scope of that method, I'll use a creation API for an object thats autoreleased before I instantiate a new object.

But, if you need to access the object anywhere else outside of the scope of the method, you *must* instantiate it and have the memory retained and stick around.

In your example above, if you're taking "`UIImage * i`" and dropping it into an image view or doing something with it only within a single method, then "`imageNamed`" is perfectly appropriate.

If you need to keep "`UIImage * i`" around for anything outside the scope of the method, use it's designated initializer instead.

Comment: Before ARC, I would agree.  However, ARC has made this point mostly moot.  It will retain the autoreleased object anyway.  Actually autoreleasing will make it live *longer* in some cases as it waits to be drained from the pool instead of being released at the end of its scope.

Comment: Is the imageNamed class method a factory method?

Comment: I've never heard Objective-C objects or methods referred to with the [Factory method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). IMHO, "`imageNamed`" is more of a convenience function.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers.  :)

Comment: Hi Michael.  Just FYI: I go the term Factory Method from Apple's documentation.  In their short one page Object Creation doc they say this:              
"A factory method is a class method that, as a convenience to clients, creates an instance of a class. A factory method combines allocation and initialization in one step and returns an autoreleased instance of the class. The names of factory methods have the following initial form:

+ (id)typeRemainderOfMethodName

+ (id)dataWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)url;"

Comment: Ahhhh, alright. [Here is Apple's "Class Factory Methods" pages in the "Concepts in Objective C Programming" documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassFactoryMethods/ClassFactoryMethods.html). I just never think of these methods as formal factory methods, but yes, I would have flunked my job interview if I had been asked a question about this.